# Dashes in group name

Tags: asp.net, configuration

I've got an ASP.NET web application that's hosted internally.

Access is controlled through settings in web.config. We allow domain groups in through the

```
<allow group="domain\mygroup" />
```

tags. The groups are Active Directory groups.

We recently renamed a bunch of groups so the convention is ID-GEO-GROUPNAME. The dashes appear to break access in web.config.

Since web.config is XML based, dashes don't seem to work. I got around the problem by creating a local (machine) group, adding the domain group to that, and using the local group name.

I'm wondering if there's a cleaner way to do this? What I have works and avoids hard-coding individual users (which I didn't want to do), but it feels kludgey to me.